# Format cell to three place decimal, unless more digits required?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel document with a series of numbers I would like formatted in a particular way. I would like the default format to be displaying three places after the decimal (zeroes included), UNLESS the number has more than three digits after the decimal.

Ex.

3 = 3.000

2.14 = 2.140

.763 = 0.763

2.5464 = 2.5464

How do I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance,

Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a Custom Format of:

```
0.000#########
```

This will go out at least 3 decimal places and truncate after 12

[image]